# How do I estimate the right parameters for a cumulative gaussian fit?

Tags: python, numpy, curve-fitting, gaussian

I'm trying to fit a cumulative Gaussian distribution to my data, however the fits are clearly wrong. Why am I getting wrong means and standard deviations? Below you find my code and output.

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from scipy.stats import norm

testrefratios=np.array([ 0.2,  0.4,  0.6,  0.8,  0.9,  1. ,  1.1,  1.2,  1.4,  1.6,  1.8])
Pn_final=np.array([ 0. ,   0. ,   0.03 , 0.35 , 0.47,  0.57 , 0.68,  0.73,  0.76 , 0.85 , 0.91])
Pd_final=np.array([ 0. ,   0.03,  0.36 , 0.85 , 0.97,  0.98 , 0.98 , 0.99 , 1.,    1.,    1.  ])

 # cumulative gaussian fit
fg = plt.figure(1); fg.clf()
ax = fg.add_subplot(1, 1, 1)
t = np.linspace(0,2, 1000) 

ax.grid(True)
ax.set_ylabel("Cumulative Probability Density")
ax.set_title("Fit to Normal Distribution")

mu1,sigma1 = norm.fit(Pn_final) # classical fit
ax.plot(t, norm.cdf(t, mu1, sigma1), alpha=.5)

mu1,sigma1 = norm.fit(Pd_final) # classical fit
ax.plot(t, norm.cdf(t, mu1, sigma1), alpha=.5)

ax.plot(testrefratios, Pn_final, 'bo',label='numerosity comparison')
ax.plot(testrefratios, Pd_final, 'ro', label='density comparison')

plt.legend(loc='lower right')


fg.canvas.draw()
```

Output:

[image: Fit results with code shown]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

At the moment, nothing you're doing is telling the system that you're trying to fit a *cumulative* Gaussian.  `norm.fit(Pn_final)` is doing its best under the assumption that `Pn_final` represents a *Gaussian*.

One way would be to use `scipy.optimize.curve_fit`, and adding

```
from scipy.optimize import curve_fit

mu1,sigma1 = curve_fit(norm.cdf, testrefratios, Pn_final, p0=[0,1])[0]
ax.plot(t, norm.cdf(t, mu1, sigma1), alpha=.5)

mu1,sigma1 = curve_fit(norm.cdf, testrefratios, Pd_final, p0=[0,1])[0]
ax.plot(t, norm.cdf(t, mu1, sigma1), alpha=.5)
```

gives me

[image: example fit]

which at least looks more believable.

Comment: This treats the `Pn_final` and `Pd_final` values as empirical cdf values, right?